# converting build.gradle to build.gradle.kts it cant not got error like Unresolved reference: artifactId

Tags: gradle, groovy, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Android project (it has a few sub projects, `proj-core`; `proj-module`) trying to convert to kotlin DSL.

In the `buildSrc` folder added the following `buildSrc/src/main/java/Versions.kt` file:

```
object DepVersions {
    const val sdkVersion = "1.0.0"
    const val versionSuffix = "-SNAPSHOT"
    const val supportlib = "28.0.0"
    const val androidBuild  = "7.4.1"  //AGP
    const val firebase      = "21.1.0"
    
......
    // test dependencies
    const val robolectric   = "4.8.1"
    const val jacoco        = "0.8.8"
    const val junitVersion  = "4.13.2"
......    
}
```

`build.gradle.kts` in `buildSrc`

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}
```

In the top level `build.gradle` it has some define and functions, this one in particular which takes in the project and generates the `group_id` from the project and put in the `project.ext`.

```
buildscript {
    ext.versions = []
    ......
}

allprojects { proj ->
    ext {
        group_id = getGroupId(proj)
        old_version = getOldVersion(proj)
    }
}

static String getGroupId(Project p) {
    String group_id = 'com.xxx.yyy'
    String pName = "doSemver"
    String localName = "local" // default for local
    String buildEnv = 'auto'
    if ((System.env.HOST && (System.env.HOST == "true"))) {
        if (p.properties.containsKey(pName)) {
            return group_id + "." + buildEnv
        } else {
            return group_id
        }
    }
    return ("${group_id}.${localName}")
}
```

The `proj-module` sub project's converted `build.gradle.kts` (the sub project's `build.gradle` and converted `build.gradle.kts` are listed below) got a few errors:

1. `project.ext`

```
group = project.ext.group_id
Unresolved reference: group_id
```

why not be set by the top level script of this?

```
allprojects { proj ->
    ext {
        group_id = getGroupId(proj)
        old_version = getOldVersion(proj)
    }
}
```

2. `project.ext.artifactId`,  why `artifactId` is not part of the `project.ext`?

```
project.ext.artifactId = "proj-module"
Unresolved reference: artifactId
```

listed the subproject's build.gradle here, it has

```
group = project.ext.group_id
version = versions.version
project.ext.artifactId = 'proj-core'

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply from: '../jacoco_coverage.gradle'

android {
    compileSdk versions.compilesdk
    buildToolsVersion versions.buildtools

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion versions.minsdk
        targetSdk versions.targetsdk
        versionCode 1
        versionName version

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${versions.kotlin}"

    api "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${versions.firebase}"
    ......
}

String getVersionTag(String intake) {
    if(project.hasProperty("doRelease"))
        return intake
    return intake+"${versions.versionSuffix}"
}
boolean localWorkspace() {
    if(findProject(":proj-core")) {
        if(!project.hasProperty("deploying"))
            return true
    }
    return false
}

//add either project dependency or maven
if( localWorkspace() ) {
    dependencies {
        api project(":proj-core")
    }
} else {
    dependencies {
        api "com.xxx.yyy:proj-core:${getVersionTag(versions.version)}"
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested

        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion "${versions.supportlib}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

after converted to `build.gradle.kts`

```
group = project.ext.group_id. //<== err: Unresolved reference: group_id
version = BuildVersions.sdkVersion
project.ext.artifactId = "proj-module" //<== err: Unresolved reference: artifactId

plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    kotlin("android")
}

apply(from = "../jacoco_coverage.gradle")
//apply from: '../jacoco_coverage.gradle'

android {
    compileSdk = BuildVersions.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion = BuildVersions.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = BuildVersions.minSdkVersion
        targetSdk = BuildVersions.targetSdkVersion

        // not exit in kts
//        versionCode = 1
//        versionName = version

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("proguard-rules.pro")
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles (getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(fileTree(mapOf("include" to listOf("*.jar"), "dir" to "libs", )))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${DepVersions.kotlin}")
    api("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${DepVersions.firebase}")
    ...
}

fun getVersionTag(intake: String): String{
    if(project.hasProperty("doRelease"))
        return intake
    return intake+"${BuildVersions.versionSuffix}"
}

fun localWorkspace(): Boolean {
    if(null != findProject(":proj-core")) {
        if(!project.hasProperty("deploying"))
            return true
    }
    return false
}

//add either project dependency or maven
if(localWorkspace()) {
    dependencies {
        api(project(":proj-core"))
    }
} else {
    dependencies {
        api("com.xxx.yyy:proj-core:${getVersionTag(BuildVersions.sdkVersion)}")
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
        if (requested.group == "com.android.support") {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                useVersion("${DepVersions.supportlib}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it needs to use project.extra

```
group = checkNotNull(project.extra.get("group_id"))
version = BuildVersions.version
project.extra.set("artifactId", "proj-core")
```